# server injected logger no output

Tags: go, logging, go-gin, zerolog

I'm trying to add a logger to my server, but for some reason it doesn't work, meaning it doesn't output to `stdout`.
The thing is, the `logger` works outside the server but not when injected. Any clue what I'm missing?

```
func InitializeLogger() zerolog.Logger {
    zerolog.ErrorStackMarshaler = pkgerrors.MarshalStack
    zerolog.SetGlobalLevel(zerolog.InfoLevel)

    output := zerolog.ConsoleWriter{Out: os.Stdout, TimeFormat: time.DateTime}
    output.FormatLevel = func(i interface{}) string {
        return strings.ToUpper(fmt.Sprintf("| %-6s|", i))
    }
    output.FormatMessage = func(i interface{}) string {
        return fmt.Sprintf("%s", i)
    }

    logger := zerolog.New(output).With().Timestamp().Logger()
    logger = logger.With().Caller().Logger()

    return logger
}
```

```
logger := util.InitializeLogger()
logger.Info().Str("service", "main").Msg("works") // works fine
```

```
server, err := api.NewServer(..., logger)

func (server *Server) ErrLogger(service string, err error) error {
    server.logger.Error().Str("service", service).Msg("test")
    return nil
}

server.ErrLogger("main", fmt.Errorf("a")) // doesn't work .. no output at all
```

Comment: You did not show api.NewServer which is responsible for "injecting" the logger.

Comment: You found it ^_^ .. that's was the issue. I wasn't initializing within 'NewServer' .. thanks !